# Doxygen: Documenting struct as a member of a struct

Tags: c, doxygen

I would like to document a struct as a member of a struct, in a style, that there will be clickable link to structure *precalculated* same as on *calibrator_calibration_t* and after click it will show me all members of *precalculated*.

Generated HTML:

[image: Generated HTML]

I've tried many different approaches but none of them worked as I needed. Any tip?

```
/**
 *  @struct filter_t
 *  @brief Filter structure 
 */
typedef struct 
{
    calibrator_calibration_t calibration;             ///< Copied calibration
    blackbox_weight_id_e weight_id;

    struct                                       
    {
        float slope;
        float above_mixed;
        float under_mixed;
        float above_male;
        float under_male;
        float above_female;
        float under_female;
        uint32_t stable_counter_minimum;
    } precalculated;          ///< Precalculated values (for faster calculation) based on settings                              
} filter_t;
```

Comment: Like this? https://codesbin.com/p/LKK1l8HEML

PS: you should use only one comment style in your code. `/** */` or `///`

Comment: Have you tried that @kuga?  With a C compiler? In C, `typedef` declarations cannot appear inside structure definitions.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? To the best of my knowledge this is not possible. Interesting idea though, maybe you should make an issue in the doxygen issue tracker.

Comment: You are mixing apples and oranges.  Your link to, for example, `calibrator_calibration_t` is directed to a *type* definition.  Your `precalculated` is a *member*.  Moreover, that member's type is an anonymous, untagged `struct` type that cannot be referenced anywhere else, so although Doxygen could, in principle, create docs in the form you describe, it is unsurprising that it *doesn't*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right, that does not compile in c: https://godbolt.org/z/8hW5aobn1. But I guess the doxygen result is what the author is looking for.

Comment: What Doxygen is doing seems reasonable. It cannot link to a definition of the anonymous type (what should it call it? some random name?) so it dumps out the definition inline instead.

Comment: @albert I am using doxygen in version 1.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the type of structure member `precalculated` to be documented with a name and a link to separate documentation of that type, then you must *give* that type a name or tag.  You have not done that.  C does not allow you to name it (via `typedef`) when its definition is inside a struct definition, however, and it is poor style to tag it in that context.

If you can get over your apparent aversion to structure tags and are also unconcerned with the stylistic problems involved, then I anticipate that adding a tag would induce Doxygen to do what you want:

```
typedef struct 
{
    calibrator_calibration_t calibration;             ///< Copied calibration
    blackbox_weight_id_e weight_id;

    struct precalc         // Note the structure tag here
    {
        float slope;
        float above_mixed;
        float under_mixed;
        float above_male;
        float under_male;
        float above_female;
        float under_female;
        uint32_t stable_counter_minimum;
    } precalculated;          ///< Precalculated values (for faster calculation) based on settings                              
} filter_t;
```

But if you are going to tag the structure type then it would be better form to move it out of the host structure definition, and if you're going to do that, then it appears that your standard convention would be to name it instead of tagging it:

```
typedef struct {
    float slope;
    float above_mixed;
    float under_mixed;
    float above_male;
    float under_male;
    float above_female;
    float under_female;
    uint32_t stable_counter_minimum;
} precalculated_t;

typedef struct 
{
    calibrator_calibration_t calibration;             ///< Copied calibration
    blackbox_weight_id_e weight_id;
    precalculated_t precalculated;                    ///< Precalculated values (for faster calculation) based on settings
} filter_t;
```